# How to close a powershell form which hasn't been closed with form.close

Tags: powershell, forms

While something in powershell to display a few details on a form I came across something I don't know how to deal with. The following code demonstrates the problem:

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms") | Out-Null;
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms ;
$Form = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Form;
$Form.Show() | out-null;
#$form.close();
```

Save this as a .ps1 and execute it from the powershell console and you willbe left with an open form. This seems like reasonable behaviour, but I am unable to see any way to close it, other than exiting from the powershell command line. The form is obviously linked to the powershell console window, but I could not find any commands to clean up open windows/forms/threads.

My question is, how could I have closed this cleanly from the command line without resorting to taskmanager?

The question is purely academic. I should have done .close and didn't. But now that this has occurred I'm curious to know how to close down this window and how the powershell console manages these sub threads.

Comment: Why don't you provide the relevant bits of your script so we may assist better?

Comment: In lieu of that, does `Stop-Process -Force -Name powershell` or `taskkill /IM powershell.exe /F` have any effect? Had you the process ID you could probably target that more granularly.

Comment: The wording of my question didn't give much to go on, so I've rewritten it and included a short example.

Comment: `$form.Dispose()` should do the trick.

Comment: If its in the code, yes. However, I meant when you execute the above code you are left with an open window which will not close. The only way to close it is to close the powershell console which launched it. This implies that the form is a child process of the powershell console. What I wanted to see was if there was any way, from the powershell command line, to close the form. I tried $form.close before posting, but I also tried looking for commands to kill child processes - without any luck.

Comment: it appears this is version specific. I tested your code in ps version 2 and reproduced the behavior you describe. In version 4 calling close or dispose at the prompt does indeed close the form.

Comment: well, good to know that I'm not doing something weird and that its just normal PS behaviour. Thanks for taking the time to investigate.